# Java - Creating Two References to the Same Object

Tags: java, design-patterns, reference

Examine the following code:

```
Object object = new Object();
objectList.add(object);
objectListTwo.add(object);
```

Is there any way to get both arrays to point to the same object, such that when I change `object` in one array, it changes in the other?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Turns, out my above code does exactly that. Problem was elsewhere in my code. My apologies for my confusion...

Comment: Actually, you have three copies of a reference to an Object `object` is the first one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "change." If you mean change as in calling setters and mutating the object, then those changes are observed. If you mean change as in completely reassigning or overwriting the variable (or reference), those changes are not observed.

Put it simpler, say you have one object, one array.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Foo[] foos = new Foo[1];
foos[0] = foo;
```

The item in the array and the variable each reference the same Foo.

```
foo.setBar(7);
int bar = foos[0].getBar(); // will get 7
```

The change to the object referenced by foo is observed inside the array.

```
foo = new Foo();
foo.setBar(94);
bar = foos[0].getBar(); // will not get 94
```

This change is not observed inside the array, as foo has been reassigned. Its setter is now mutating a different object entirely.

Comment: What do you mean by "reassigning or overwriting the object"?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Turns out that the root of my problem, was elsewhere in my code. But your answer definitely cleared things up.

Comment: @Oli, is the text now unclear? You apparently caught me prior to some code samples.

Comment: I think you should reword it as "reassigning or overwriting the **reference**".

Answer (score 6):

Both Lists point to the same Object. Java is passing a reference to the object (by value).

Comment: Wrong - Java passes *everything* by value.  In the case of non-primitives, the thing that's passed is not an object; it's a reference to an object.  See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaPassesByValue

Comment: Java doesn't pass objects, and it doesn't pass objects by reference either. http://blog.tmorris.net/java-is-pass-by-value/